# Classes in Java

Tags: java, mysql, swing, jdbc

I'm trying to create a quiz application using Netbeans and I have to admit I'm new to Java. I've tried to connect it to MySQL and have been successful. Problem arrived when i realized i must create a class with the info from the welcome screen and inherit the data throughout the program. So I created my classes viz. BaseClass and ChildClass. After this my jButton just wouldn't do anything. Here's the code.

```
class BaseClass
{
    String jdbcurl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/quiz";
    String user="root";
    String pass="sql";
    int num = (int)(Math.random() * 1000);
    String name = jTextField1.getText();
    int age=Integer.parseInt(jTextField2.getText());

}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    class ChildClass extends BaseClass
    {
        public void input() {
            try {
                Class.forName("java.sql.Driver");
                Connection con = (Connection) DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcurl,user,pass);
                Statement st = con.createStatement();
                String query = "insert into DB values ('" + name + "'," + age + ",0," + num + ");";
                st.executeUpdate(query);
                st.close();
                con.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Error in code");
            }
            Question1 w2 = new Question1();
            w2.setVisible(true);

        } // TODO add your handling code here:
    }
}
```

Any help is appreciated! :)

Comment: A reaction to a button click means that there should be an action listener implemented somewhere. I cannot see it in your code. Please revise your example, to make the question clearer.

Comment: You're loading the wrong driver. Actually, you aren't explicitly loading any driver at all (the real driver might already have been loaded by `ServiceLoader` if it's a JDBC4 compatible driver). But that's a different problem. I'd also add `e.printStackTrace()` inside the catch so that you can see any causes of the problem in rich detail in the stdout.

Comment: does this code even compile? you can not define a class inside a method the way you have defined, also BaseClass seems to close before the next method starts.  Assuming this is all inside another class, ChildClass needs to be pulled out as a first thing. I think you should paste the entire code in the *.java from which this is an extract.

Answer (score 3):

where is your JButton ? you need to add actionListener to that like

```
jButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event){
    //now do your things here...
  }
});`
```